# How to move a floating-point constant value into an xmm register?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

Is the only way to move a value into an xmm register by first moving the value into an integer register, dunno what they are called, and then into the xmm register e.g.

```
mov   [eax], (float)1000   ; store to memory
movss xmm1,[eax]           ; reload
```

or

```
mov        eax,  1000       ; move-immediate integer
cvtsi2ss   xmm1,eax         ; and convert
```

or is there another way? Is there a way to directly move a value into a xmm register, something along the lines of: `movss xmm1,(float)1000`?

Comment: You can also load from memory. There is no immediate version.

Answer (score 7):

There are no instructions to load an SSE register with an immediate.  The common idiom is to load the value you need from a global constant:

```
const   dd 1000.0

...

        movss xmm0,[const]
```

Comment: You can of course do it with 2 instructions using `mov eax, imm32` / `movd xmm0, eax`, but yes, static constants are often best.  Related: [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the assembler.

UASM:

```
LOADSS xmm1,1000.0
```

ASMC, FASM, POASM, JWasm:

```
mov eax,1000.0
movd xmm1,eax
```

NASM:

```
mov eax,__?float32?__(1000.0)
movd xmm1,eax
```

MASM, YASM, Sol_Asm:

```
mov eax,447A0000h
movd xmm1,eax
```

You can also use a macro which creates constants in the data section. UASM already has a built-in macro `FP4`:

```
movss xmm1,FP4(1000.0)
```

If you use ASMC, POASM, JWasm or MASM, you can define this macro:

```
FP4 MACRO value
 LOCAL vname
 .const
 align 4
 vname REAL4 value
 .code
 EXITM <vname>
ENDM
```

Comment: The choice of whether to load a constant from memory or bounce an immediate through an integer register is independent of the assembler.  It's weird that for MASM you show a macro that creates a constant in `.data`, while others use an immediate.  Also, these are "assemblers", not "compilers".  The difference is that it's up to you to make optimization choices like immediate vs. load from `.rdata`, not leaving it to a compiler to pick the best one.

Comment: `LOADSS` is presumably some kind of macro or pseudo-instruction provided by UASM.  I can't find documentation on it; do you know what actual instructions it expands to?

Comment: LOADSS expands to mov eax,1000.0; vmovd xmm1,eax