# X86: How to set lower half of xmm0 to 0, without affecting the upper half?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd, micro-optimization

I use a system where xmm0 has 128 bit.
I want to set [63...0] to zero, whithout affecting [127...64].
I use:

```
MOV RAX, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
MOVQ xmm2, RAX
PSHUFD xmm2, xmm2, 0b00001111
PAND xmm1, xmm2
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create the constant somewhat more efficiently via

```
pcmpeqd xmm2,xmm2       ; xmm2 = all-ones.  Needs any ALU port
pslldq  xmm2, 8         ; left shift by 8 bytes.  Needs the shuffle port

PAND    xmm1, xmm2
```

(See also [Agner Fog's optimization guide](https://agner.org/optimize/); he has a section on creating constants on the fly.  Also [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly))

Or as @RossRidge suggested, using a memory source operand for the constant may be most efficient if you need it often enough to stay hot in cache, but can't just hoist it out of a loop and keep it in a register.

---

**Or blend in a new low 8 bytes of zeros**.

```
pxor   xmm2, xmm2       ; xmm2=0; very efficient on Intel CPUs; no back-end uop

movsd  xmm1, xmm2       ; runs on port5 only on Intel CPUs, like shuffles.
```

(As a load from memory, [`movsd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsd) zero-extends.  But for reg-reg moves it  and `movss` leave the destination upper part unmodified.)

**Alternate ways to blend are more efficient but require more than SSE2:**

- SSE4.1: `pblendw xmm1, xmm2, 0b00001111` - Worse on everything (or equal speed but worse code-size).  Still only runs on port5 on Intel.  Ryzen runs `movsd xmm,xmm` on even more ports than `pblendw`.  Low-power Atom/Silvermont runs movsd on more ports than pblendw, but Goldmont and KNL have 2/clock throughput for this and movsd.  So it's still never better than movsd.
- **SSE4.1 [`blendpd xmm1, xmm2, 0b01`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blendpd)** (or `blendps`) - as efficient as vpblendd, but will incur bypass forwarding latency if used between integer instructions.  If you're bottlenecked on throughput this might be ok, especially if you have to avoid back-end pressure.
- AVX2: `vpblendd xmm1, xmm1, xmm2, 0b0011` - runs on any ALU port on any AVX2 CPU.

Some CPUs might also have a bypass delay for `movsd` between integer instructions, but Sandybridge-family is pretty forgiving for shuffles.

Equally efficient as `movsd` on some CPUs, requiring only SSE1:

- `movhlps xmm1, xmm2`  - replace the low qword of xmm1 with the high qword of xmm2 (also zero).  Less efficient on Ryzen or Silvermont.

Similarly, `shufpd` and `shufps` could copy the top half of `xmm1` into the top half of a zeroed register.  (Useful if you don't want to destroy the original reg).  But you can do that with `movsd` just as easily and more efficiently.

---

Also possible: `movlps xmm, [mem]` load of zeros, possibly that you just stored to the stack.  It doesn't allow a register source operand, and needs a port5 uop on Intel (shuffle / uncommon blend).  It can micro-fuse into one fused-domain uop but it's mostly worse than `pand` with a memory source because it can run on fewer ports.

---

#### With a single `insertps` instruction:

[SSE4.1 `insertps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/insertps) can do this in one instruction. (Insert an element from itself to itself, then apply zeroing). It's an FP shuffle so some CPUs might have extra bypass-forwarding latency between it and surrounding integer instructions, but probably not Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs.  (Nehalem would have this penalty, but is old enough not to care about.)

```
 insertps  xmm1, xmm1, 0b00_00_0011    ; fields are: src elem, dst elem, zmask
  ; NASM syntax allows _ between digits in a number, like C++ allows '
```

If you need to do it repeatedly, can be worth creating a vector constant for a cheaper instruction, like `pand` or `vpblendd`

Clang optimizes `v = _mm_insert_ps(v,v, 0b00'00'0011);` into `vxorps` / `vblendps xmm,xmm, 3`, same as for using GNU C native vector syntax to do `v[0] = 0;` on a `__m128d`, so that confirms I got the constant correct. [**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBm0gAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMXG2mPa5DEIETMQE6T5%2BXGUVqdW1BPlhkdGx0go1dQ2ZzQMdXYXFfQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CarbngsLMEExMEAdAh72CYaAIK3dwD6TyxcZgAc6NsAXtGoT1oqAA7tEEGIqBAXm9Pt8AG7TXYAdis9226O2cJMAFYLBocQARXarIn41aou4Y7bETAEBYMTF7CkmJEEx6PaHvD54X7/QEgsEQp4nKGvLk8hHIilUrG4/HYol7UlM9EAelV202hmA2y8SgUmIi9AY6HiBuCA0wTG%2BqComPiRtc6FI2xOxAwXmQwR1mFUpyY2wMBEYyAAnq67QQEJhNWJ6MRdfrtlG8AbgYQENsogRQYxXYJMMBovmFAwFI8qTS6cQGVjyezWez7pzPrz3fzgU9ypgWE8zaKYR9MYiWdKMbK8YTicr62iMVX6YzZw9G/cm88xa2/u2gcDwbQqMKy9ECP2W0PJaOK%2BPp9tXr2LSe%2BwoIHDSG/thoIhoNGAOD%2B/x/LguGmJlrzVDUtSMbYWCYABrTADSjGMFFYGMmAUFhtgwtsAV3QUDxdBRUGTBBU1dJDo2pPBgAQAhNQEMZBHA6laUXOtmVXO4OFmWhOGxXg/H/XhUE4NxrGsbZiIWJZdjMVYeFIAhNB42Y4JAVZVnOAA2VYNG0yQfw%2BVYAE5JGxSRLP0ThJEElTSFEjheAUEANCUlTZjgWAYEQFBUBYeI6GichKDQAKgpiYB3jMUgsDhPAlgANTwTBgQAeXiRhOEUmhaGDYgXIgCJ7IiYJalDbLeDCthBDShhaAq4TYp7bVxCa/AaQcPA4UQ%2BzfUwZAvGDSryALPimtoPAImIcqPCwezTkOSrZioAxgAUZLUoyrLuF4fhBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1Ca3RmgMIwUAkyx9CmlzIFmVB4kqFyOAAWjS1Ztm%2B2DFiuEkFDg0MDAQgGBnQJVgAYLwHosMwtBaAbKhcE1hiaUhAmCboil6ZpshSARsayJJSYYCYehiUZuy6gR2iGTxGj0Ox0baQZOnxyYidsbnydGbmacJunZmkxZjt4/i7KaxztlUD5tO%2BgztmAZBkG2d5zjMbYIFwQgSDkhTpl4ZThOmNSNK0jRVm0jQzG07EPjMJEzHeVZpHG2zSBYEBsTcoTUcc5zXPcy3SC83z5lPIaQogMLAvjUI0M4JWVbVjWtZ1xTMHwIgznQPR9uEURxBO0vzrUezrtIYEZviZbrI4ATSGDkTODSob4iG7ZbUV5XVckdXNe1sxdf1jxwvjE2QPNjzZmja1eggGWOF9/3A/b%2BzQ9scOLa0K3SHUzTzjth2nZdt2Pfk73OFWOWQ84BfI%2BjiAkCTiKE6/%2BMUFuqKgc3JxQSpgTa6VMpCRynQfKhVipNVKswYgjVFLVUYAQOqDV7JYFgkYNqqMOqcx6l9VG/VBrDV2qNYM41UaTWmrNDAyxUaLX9rtFaa0NopQgTtHKshDoV2kFXJQNcrqxH0Nqe6lhrBPQiC9NeDkPqpC%2Br9f6gNajIBBgSMGEN4Ixm%2BjDOGCMkYo2cgzDGEBXBC1xiaUWUxiaU0qFYkmlRbH8w5ozKogtWYjDRh45mPMCi03Zl4jIOMxh1FceLOYMlpYtzbh3BynBB6ZxHlBHUXBsTn3PvrQ2hc55mwjkfa2Z9NKlLKeUluvsEl7xcm5Q%2BqkW5mCfp3JyhSGk9QKqkEAkggA)

GCC unfortunately uses `vmovsd` or even `vpinsrq` from an integer register for `v[0] = 0;`, even when optimizing for `-march=skylake` so it should know that those aren't the cheapest instructions for that CPU.