# Why does SSE/AVX lack loading an immediate value?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, instruction-set, immediate-operand

As far as I know, there is no instruction in SSE/AVX for loading an immediate. One workaround is loading a value to a normal register and `movd`, but compilers seem to think this is more costly than loading from memory even for a single scalar value.

This makes memory access necessary every time doing an operation with common constants such as `1`, `0x80000000`, `0x7fffffff`, `0x3f800000`, `0x3f000000`, etc. Well, having these values encoded in the machine code will occupy 4 bytes each, but so does a 32-bit absolute or `rip`-relative address, and I believe an immediate load is cheaper than any sort of memory load.

I always thought something like `movss xmm, imm32` or `broadcastss xmm, imm32` would be nice to have, but there must be a reason for not making such instructions. Why was it designed this way?

Comment: By contrast, ARM NEON does have instructions that broadcast an immediate value into a vector. Reasons that are posted as answer won't be convincing if they would apply equally as much to NEON.

Comment: This is likely to be unanswerable unless somebody from the SSE/AVX design team sees the question and is willing to discuss what they were thinking.

Comment: The standard solution for this is to load a constant from memory.  This is how the instruction set was designed and it's the same on MMX and the x87 floating point unit.

Comment: Several of those constants (where all the set bits are contiguous at one end of the register) can be generated in 2 instructions, starting with `pcmped xmm0,xmm0` (all-ones).  See [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085059) and Agner Fog's guide.  But 2 instructions is still worse than 1, or a memory source operand, so compilers generally don't do that.

Comment: @fuz I don't know much about the history of x86, but I think x87 was designed to load a constant from memory because it was originally a stack-machine-like coprocessor, and MMX was built on top of x87. SSE was a totally new design, so it doesn't have to follow x87 and MMX.

Comment: AVX-512 has `vpbroadcastd z/y/zmm, eax`, so you can construct any set1_epi32() constant with a mov-immediate + that.  (Strangely compilers do sometimes use that, but not pcmpeqd / psrld).

Comment: I've wondered if lack of mov-immediate to vector reg was a matter of never decoding more than a 1-byte immediate for vector instructions.  Or some other quirk of convenience / inconvenience for existing Intel microarchitectures.  Intel has definitely gimped their ISA for short-term convenience in the past, like SSE1 with `cvtsi2ss` and `sqrtss` merging into an XMM (false dep) instead of zero extending, because P3 handles 128-bit vectors as two 64-bit halves, so zero-extending would take 2 uops to write a full reg.  GCC spends extra dep-breaking `pxor` instructions to work around it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: But even a one-byte immediate could have been very useful.  The NEON move-immediate only includes an 8-bit immediate (with a few different options for how to decode it), and that probably covers 95% of use cases.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Right, yes, 1 byte might actually be a better design choice than 32-bit.  (Although ARM already has complex decoding for immediates for Thumb mode, while x86 at most does sign-extension.  Except for bitfields for control operands for stuff like `roundps`, but that's kinda different.) Still, not a great argument.  Possibly something microarchitectural about getting immediates used as values, as opposed to shuffle or other control operands for SIMD instructions.