# How to set all the values in AVX ymm register to be the same (all are 0/1/specific value)?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, avx, avx2

I'm new to assembly code and SSE/AVX instructions. Now, I want to assign a specific value to all locations in 256-bit YMM registers, but I don't know if the final result is correct.

1. To assign **0** or **1** to `ymm0`:

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "vpxor    %%ymm0, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t" // all are 0
    or
    "VPCMPEQB    %%ymm0, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t" // all are 1
: : :);
```

GDB result shows that:

```
// all are 0
ymm0
{v8_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
v4_double = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
v32_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 32 times>}, 
v16_int16 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>}, 
v8_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
v4_int64 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
v2_int128 = {0x0, 0x0}}

// all are 1
ymm0           
{v8_float = {0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff}, 
v4_double = {0x7fffffffffffffff, 0x7fffffffffffffff, 0x7fffffffffffffff, 0x7fffffffffffffff}, 
v32_int8 = {0xff <repeats 32 times>}, 
v16_int16 = {0xffff <repeats 16 times>}, 
v8_int32 = {0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff}, 
v4_int64 = {0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff}, 
v2_int128 = {0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}}
```

2. To set **0xA** to all locations (both high and low 128-bits) in `ymm0`:

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
      "movq $0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, %%rcx\n"
      "vmovq %%rcx, %%xmm0\n" 
      "vpbroadcastq %%xmm0, %%ymm0\n": : :);
```

GDB result shows that:

```
ymm0           
{v8_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
v4_double = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 
v32_int8 = {0xaa <repeats 32 times>}, 
v16_int16 = {0xaaaa <repeats 16 times>}, 
v8_int32 = {0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaa}, 
v4_int64 = {0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}, 
v2_int128 = {0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}
```

**Questions:**

1. What does the GDB result (structure) mean? E.g., *v8_float*, *v4_double*, *v32_int8*, etc.
2. In the second case (**0xA**), why are the *v8_float* and *v4_double* always **0**?
3. How can I assign the value (e.g., 'a') to all locations in YMM (including both high and low 128-bits)?

P.S [VPBROADCAST — Load Integer and Broadcast](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your inline asm is broken: missing a `"%ymm0"` clobber to tell the compiler you wrote that register.  You even used `asm("" : : :)` Extended asm syntax to explicitly tell the compiler there were no clobbers.  Or better, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm - write a separate function, or use intrinsics and look at compiler-generated asm.

---

`v8_float` means to interpret the 256 bits as a Vector of 8x `float`.  i.e. `__m256` in Intel Intrinsics.

`v32_int8` is a vector of 32x `int8_t`, printing each byte separately.  You can use `p /x $ymm0.v8_int32` if that's how you want to look at it.

---

(2) Integer `0xa` is the bit-pattern for a very tiny subnormal float or double.  Try putting that in as the "Hexadecimal Representation" on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.

(3) You already did broadcast `0xa` to all 64 nibbles in your 32-byte YMM register, as you can see from the `v2_int128 = {0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}` output showing both halves being all `0xaa` bytes.

If you actually wanted `_mm256_set1_epi8(0x0a)` (broadcast that to every byte), you should have written `0x0a0a0a0a` instead of `0xaaaaaaaa`.  (There's no need to use a qword immediate; `vpbroadcastd` runs just as fast, but `mov $0x0a0a0a0a, %eax` is a smaller and faster instruction.)

https://godbolt.org/z/z18nMT3fd shows GCC and clang compiling that a function that returns `_mm256_set1_epi8(0x0a)` (and another that broadcasts a function arg, not a constant).  GCC11.3 does constant-propagation and loads 32 bytes from `.rodata`.  GCC12.1 unwisely uses your strategy of mov r64, imm64 and `vmovq`.

Clang uses `vbroadcastsd` (which is the same thing as `vpbroadcastq`) from an 8-byte memory source.  4-byte broadcast-loads are just as efficient.  (Unlike byte or word which cost an extra ALU uop: https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/)

AVX-512 introduces `vpbroadcastb/w/d/q ymm0, eax` which combines the `vmovd` with the broadcast.  But without that, yeah you generally want AVX2 `vpbroadcastb/w/d/q ymm, xmm` if data is coming from an integer register.  (I'm using Intel syntax here, like the vendor manuals; reverse it as usual for AT&T syntax if you prefer that.)

---

AFAIK, there isn't a good trick to generate 0xa (0b1010) on the fly from all-ones.  Some other constants like 0x1 or 0x8000000 can be generated with 2 instructions, starting with `vpcmpeqd same,same,same` for all-ones.  (See [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly))

Comment: 0xa (or any other byte) could be generated from an all-zero vector using vgf2p8affineqb if you have it (put zero vector in both arguments, put the desired byte as the immediate)