# vpbroadcastb vs mov+vmovq+vpbroadcastq AVX2

Tags: assembly, gcc, compiler-optimization, avx, avx2

I want to move a byte to each byte in a YMM register.
GCC 11 and older uses this method (FASM):

```
vmovdqa ymm1, YWORD [.byte32]

   align 32
.byte32:
 dq 0x3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f
 dq 0x3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f
 dq 0x3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f
 dq 0x3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f
```

But from GCC 12 to newer, the method is changed to :

```
mov rax, 0x3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f
vmovq xmm1, rax
vpbroadcastq ymm1, xmm1
```

But why ?????? When it is possible to just do this:

```
vpbroadcastb ymm1, BYTE [.3f]

.3f db 0x3f
```

Here the third one is cheaper (the first one is more cheaper but not for too many brodcasts).
But the second one is more expensive in latency and even code-size ... Why GCC chose the second method and which method is better at all ?

Comment: GCC12 and later changed to constructing constants on the fly instead of loading them, but is bad at it, only knowing the general-case pattern for 64-bit patterns.  It's very silly that it doesn't at *least* use `mov eax, 0x3f3f3f3f` / `vmovd` / `vpbroadcastd` to avoid a 10-byte `mov imm64`.  See also [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085059) .

Comment: If you're going to load, dword broadcasts are free (in the load port), byte / word broadcasts need an ALU uop on Intel.  So I'd use `vpbroadcastd` from a constant in `.rodata`.  I'm curious about why GCC decided to change, but haven't checked their git or SVN for the change.  Perhaps they found too many cache misses for infrequently-run loops, or excess D-cache pressure or conflict misses, vs. I-cache pressure being less significant.

Comment: See https://uops.info/ for uop breakdowns for instructions.   (`vpbroadcastd/q`, `vbroadcasti128`, and even `vmovsl/hdup ymm`, only need load-port uops on Intel.  So I'd normally expand a byte constant up to 4 bytes for a dword broadcast, or create it on the fly from an all-ones.  But that's non-trivial in this case, you'd need something like `vpsrlw ymm, 10` / `vpacksswb` which isn't great.)